# WordPress Woo-commerce knowledge sharing is requested and solution

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

1- Where-to-buy functionality with Google Maps integration for traditional dealers and special links to E-commerce partners’ websites.

2 - “Choose Your Product” - a guided selling tool to allow users make an informed decision.

If this is possible in WordPress and Woocommerce then how.

## WordPress

Comment: Same question asked over here but the answer is not good to go. To read that question Click on the link

https://themeforest.net/forums/thread/survey-shop-assistant-plugin-woocommerce/154138